# How can I update a text value of Label in non-controller class of Javafx?

Tags: javafx, fxml

another class is the controller, in a non-controller class of javafx, I can get the Label, but can't update the text value, and there is no any error... any one have the experience, pls help

trying to set the Label text value from a non-controller class

fxml:

```
<AnchorPane  maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.ning.fx1.HelloController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="tf1" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="52.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="tf2" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="102.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="tf3" layoutX="68.0" layoutY="151.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="117.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlerBtn1" text="Button" />
      <Label fx:id="label1" layoutX="402.0" layoutY="106.0" text="" />
      <Label fx:id="label2" layoutX="429.0" layoutY="293.0" text="init" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

this is the controller:

```
public class HelloController{
    @FXML
    public Label label1;
    @FXML
    public Label label2;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf1;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf2;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf3;
    @FXML
    private Button btn1;



    @FXML
    private void handlerBtn1(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException, SchedulerException {
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(tf2.getText());
        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(num1+num2));

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        label1.textProperty().bind(timer.messageProperty());
        new Thread(timer).start();

        JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzJob.class)
                .withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(4)
                        .repeatForever())
                .build();
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job1,trigger);
        label2.setText("handler");
    }


}
```

I want update label2.

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job, Initializable {





    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("jobbbbbbbbbb");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = fxmlLoader.<Parent>load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        HelloController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.label2.setText("2222222");


    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        System.out.println("init");

    }
}
```

from the quartz task class, I use "controller.label2.setText("2222222");"
I debug it, it can get the Label object, but have no effect

another uncorrelated class：

```
public class Timer extends Task<String> {
    @Override
    protected String call() throws Exception {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println("calling "+i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            updateMessage(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateMessage(String s) {
        super.updateMessage(s);
    }


}
```

sorry, my code is nonsence

---

after

now I can update the element value by set the scene as a static object.
but it looks weird ...

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    static Scene scene;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 500, 500);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
//        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) ->
//                {
//                    System.out.println("ttttttttttttt"+t);
//                    System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+e.getStackTrace());
//                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
//                    alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
//                    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
//                    alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
//
//                    alert.showAndWait();
//
//                }
//
//        );


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();

    }
}
```

in a task class :

```
Label label = (Label)HelloApplication.scene.lookup("#label1");
        label.textProperty().unbind();
        label.setText("success");
```

------ in the end-----

actually, when I load the FXML again, then I get the Scene , but the scene is not the original scene.

I found there is many ways to finish it, such as us construsctor to pass the Label, thanks guys, this is not a good question.

Comment: Could you provide some code so we can see the problem, it's a good practice to provide a minimal sample :)

Comment: realy thanks your comment, I have commited my code

Comment: Just so I understand -> You have a JavaFX UI which you loaded in FXML and is backed by a controller.  You have a Quartz job that executes at specified intervals.  When the Quartz job runs, you want the execution to set text in a label in the existing UI, updating the UI with the new text,  You don't want to load a completely new FXML and UI (even though you have done that in your question) you just want to modify something that is already there.  Is that a correct understanding of what you are asking?

Comment: @jewelsea yes, I just want to verify if quartz jobs can update a FXML scene . I see the label have a property name "accessible role", may it's about accessibility? don't how to handle it

Comment: No. [Accessibility](https://m2.material.io/design/usability/accessibility.html#understanding-accessibility) is for stuff such as allowing somebody who is blind to read the text in your app.

Comment: See [applying MVC in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx).  But also understand that your quartz thread and JavaFX thread are different, so you *also* need to use `Platform.runLater` to update any property that will result in a UI update.

Comment: @jewelsea I have tried it, can't work,  quartz object should not block the main thread, as the window is runing smooth. quartz is external maven lib, maybe I should find a  javafx method alternative

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense.  Quartz does not run on the main thread.  It uses its own scheduler and thread pool.  It can't block or interfere with another thread unless you do something strange, causing (for example) a deadlock or race condition.

Comment: JavaFX has [ScheduledService](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html), though the feature set is different from Quartz, some of the core concepts (periodically executed service) are similar.  Either approach might work for you as long as you code your implementation correctly.  Also, your "uncorrelated class", which implements a JavaFX task is another option (bind your label to the task message property).

Comment: *"quartz object should not block the main thread"* `Platform.runLater(...)` returns immediately and does not block anything. [Read the docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)). To execute something periodically in a JavaFX application, it may be better to use JavaFX API classes rather than Quartz. Either the `javafx.concurrent` API as mentioned in a previous comment, or the animation API may be applicable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/2189127

Comment: @jewelsea yes, many thanks ! it's hard to try quartz, now I use ScheduledService, it's very   efficient

Comment: @James_D yes , Platform.runLater  and  scheduledservice are make it work,  thanks bro

Comment: If you're using `ScheduledService`, you shouldn't really need `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: no need, ScheduledService need to override a createTask(), it's async function

Comment: This looks like a bunch of code thrown together without any logical structure. As pointed out earlier, try to learn a pattern like [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx). If you need to pass data to a controller, you can also use the ideas in the `MVC` to pass the data.

Comment: Is `QuartzJob` a `Controller` for its own individual `FXML` file? If not, why is it `Initializable`? Is `public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext)` valid? I thought `FXML` methods needed some type of `Action` or `Event` where `JobExecutionContext` is located.

Comment: @SedJ601 yes, this code have no logical, I just want to try update a scene from another class. but now I found the real question:  when I update the scene from a task class, I load the FXML again, the Label is not the orignal scene, maybe it's just a copy, Now I can update it by set the orignal scene as a static object ,  I don't know if it is rational， I will paste my code to blow

Comment: What about passing your Controller reference as variable to the scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `FXMLLoader::load` you are creating a new object graph and controller. That means the controller instance you "get" in your job is not the same instance attached to the UI. In other words, the label you are updating is not the one visible to the user. You need to find a way to pass the controller, or at least the label, to your job.

I do not have much experience with Quartz, but from browsing the documentation and reading a few other Stack Overflow Q&As, there are three main ways to do this:

1. Put the FXML controller instance in the job's data map.

   If you do this, make sure the scheduler's data store does not support persistence. Even if the FXML controller could be easily serialized, which should not be attempted, you would not get the correct FXML controller instance back when it is deserialized.

   From what I can tell, the `RAMDataStore` implementation, which I believe is the default, is the best for your use case.
2. Put the FXML controller instance in the scheduler's context.
3. Set your own job factory on the scheduler so that you can manually pass the FXML controller instance to your job when the factory is invoked.

For approaches 1 and 2, you can get the stored object in the job via the `JobExecutionContext`.

I also recommend you use a proper application architecture such as MVC or MVVM. Ideally, Quartz should not know about JavaFX and your view classes should not know about Quartz. And if you use MVC, MVVM, or similar, then you would pass the model to the Quartz job, not the FXML controller (nor any other view class). Additionally, a Quartz job is not an FXML controller, meaning it makes no sense for the job class to implement `Initializable`.

That all said, Quartz seems like overkill for what you are trying to do. It would probably be much easier to use JavaFX's `ScheduledService` or even standard Java's `ScheduledExecutorService`. Though in both cases, you will still need a way to reference the correct FXML controller (or model) instance.

And finally, regardless of which technology you use, you **must** ensure the label's text is updated on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

---

## Example

Here is an example of passing an FXML controller to a Quartz job via the job's data map. Note it is only meant to demonstrate passing "custom" objects to a job, not necessarily how to structure an application.

**MainView.java**

```java
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class MainView extends VBox {

  @FXML private Label label;
  @FXML private Button button;

  private Runnable onScheduleQuartzJob;

  public MainView() {
    var loader = new FXMLLoader(MainView.class.getResource("/MainView.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.setRoot(this);
    try {
      loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
  }

  public void setLabelText(String text) {
    label.setText(text);
  }

  public void setOnScheduleQuartzJob(Runnable onScheduleQuartzJob) {
    this.onScheduleQuartzJob = onScheduleQuartzJob;
  }

  @FXML
  private void handleScheduleQuartzJob(ActionEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    if (onScheduleQuartzJob != null) {
      button.setDisable(true);
      onScheduleQuartzJob.run();
    }
  }
}
```

**MainView.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
         alignment="CENTER" spacing="10">
    <Label fx:id="label" text="Hello, World!"/>
    <Button fx:id="button" text="Schedule Quartz job!" onAction="#handleScheduleQuartzJob">
        <tooltip>
            <Tooltip text="Schedules a Quartz job to change the label's text."/>
        </tooltip>
    </Button>
</fx:root>
```

**UpdateLabelJob.java**

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class UpdateLabelJob implements Job {

  public static final String MAIN_VIEW_KEY = MainView.class.getName();

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    var view = (MainView) context.getMergedJobDataMap().get(MAIN_VIEW_KEY);
    Platform.runLater(() -> view.setLabelText("Text set from Quartz job!"));
  }
}
```

**Main.java**

```java
package sample;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class Main extends Application {

  private Scheduler scheduler;

  @Override
  public void init() throws Exception {
    scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    var root = new MainView();
    root.setOnScheduleQuartzJob(() -> scheduleUpdateLabelJob(root));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Quartz Example");
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void scheduleUpdateLabelJob(MainView view) {
    var details =
        JobBuilder.newJob(UpdateLabelJob.class)
            .withIdentity("update-label-job", "example")
            .build();
    // Add MainView instance to the job's data map
    details.getJobDataMap().put(UpdateLabelJob.MAIN_VIEW_KEY, view);

    var trigger =
        TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .forJob(details)
            .withIdentity("update-label-trigger", "example")
            .startAt(computeJobDelay())
            .build();

    try {
      scheduler.scheduleJob(details, trigger);
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to schedule job", ex);
    }
  }

  private Date computeJobDelay() {
    var instant = Instant.now().plusSeconds(3);
    return Date.from(instant);
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() throws Exception {
    scheduler.shutdown();
  }
}
```